# What is the weakest magnetic field that can practically be measured?

Tags: experimental-physics, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I would like to be able to measure magnetic fields that are generated by nerve impulses in extremities like in fingers. 
I know that they are very weak: about 100 mV electric potential would give us about current 10 mA if resistance = 1/10 Ohm, but interested in measuring magnetic fields.

**How many rounds should you have in a coil to measure 10 mA current?**

The jumping of electrons from one level to another may become a problem in this case. However, I am not sure where and how.

Assume that there is a steady current in the situation so Biot-Savart law. 
The radius of the nerve is r = 0.003m.

Comment: You have a problem with units here, you say you want to measure *magnetic* fields, but you quote a strength in mV which is a unit of *electric* potential.

Comment: @dmckee I fixed the confusion. I think the answer should be get by Biot-Savart law when assuming that r =  0.003m. Let's assume that there is a steady current in the situation, probably wrong assumption, but not sure which law to use for not steady currents.

Comment: It's possible to measure very weak magnetic fields, indeed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: you should promote your comment to an answer. I was about to add an answer referring to SQUIDs but it would say little more than your comment. The OP obviously hasn't encountered SQUIDs since he's thinking of using a coil.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer: I agree with John Rennie. You should promote that into the answer. Just look at  the upvotes you got on a  *Comment* (how often are comments upvoted anyway?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

SQUIDs are sensitive enough to measure fields as low as 5 aT (5×10−18 T).
So 5 aT is the best one that can be reached at the moment.